# html link in a ul is not lined up

Tags: html, wordpress, css

I have a link in a  and it isnt lining up.  You can view it here http://104.236.190.78/technology/
I added this css to try and shove the links down:

```
a{
 padding-top: 3%;
}
```

I also tried that used 30px and it also didnt work.  Any help is appriceated.  Thanks.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Your screen.css (bootstrap) has a line-height:1em for some reason, this css should override it.

Add this to your CSS

```
body .content a {
    line-height: 0;
}
```

Comment: that didn't work do you have any other ideas? Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 a{
     line-height: 33px;
  }
```

Comment: that didn't work do you have any other ideas?  Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: try  line-height: 33px !important;

Answer (score 0):

In your html document (line 480) you are globally styling your anchors with the following code `a{line-height: 33px;}` which is causing your footer link to be misaligned. Take a look at the code and make some adjustments or delete it if it unnecessary.